# jQuery DataTables - Sort by object's property

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables, datatables-1.10

One of my table's columns needs to render a link based on several object's properties. It's simplified definition would look something like this:

```
columns: [{
    "data": "obj",
    "render": function(data, type, row) {
        return "<a href='" + obj.x + "'>" + obj.y + "</a>";
    }
} ... ]
```

It does render as intended, although I would also like the column to be sortable by obj.y property. This is where my problem begins, as I found the mechanics a little bit confusing, but maybe hopefully I just keep missing some obvious solution.

I've attempted to add my custom sorting to jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, and then set the column's sType, and else to add data-order/data-sort attribute to each cell during rendering, but neither of those worked - the column still seems to apply it's default ordering.

Is there any recommended approach I should try?
I'm using plugin's version 1.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the render function has a `type` parameter just for cases like this.

This parameter takes values like 'display','sort','filter', which indicate the context the data is being rendered on.

So in your case, you should check if `type === 'sort'` and then return the data you want datatables to consider when sorting by that column:

```
"render": function(data, type, row) {
    if(type==='sort'){
        return obj.y;
    }
    return "<a href='" + obj.x + "'>" + obj.y + "</a>";
}
```